# How to fix custom listview set wrong value?

Tags: java, android, listview

i have create a custom listview with textview, switch. When i scroll down, this reuse the interface of old item, the text "OFF" just set on first item but when I pulled it down, it was put in other positions

```
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    connectService = new ConnectService();
    currentItem = listFurniture.get(i);
    if (view == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_furniture, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


    if(currentItem.getTypeitem().equals(Constans.TYPE_QUAT)){
        viewHolder.aSwitch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.tvSpeed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(currentItem.getStatus().equals("0")){
            viewHolder.tvSpeed.setText("OFF");
        }else{
            viewHolder.tvSpeed.setText("Speed "+ currentItem.getStatus());
        }


    }
    viewHolder.tvSpeed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (currentItem.getStatus()){

                case "0":
                    currentItem.setStatus("1");
                    break;
                case "1":
                    currentItem.setStatus("2");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    currentItem.setStatus("3");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    currentItem.setStatus("0");
                    break;
            }
            if(currentItem.getStatus().equals("0")){
                viewHolder.tvSpeed.setText("OFF");
            }else{
                viewHolder.tvSpeed.setText("Speed "+ currentItem.getStatus());
            }
            //  viewHolder.tvSpeed.setText("Speed "+ currentItem.getStatus());
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you need the trickery with a `ViewHolder`? Try without it. Also, you probably don't want to create `new ConnectService()` in a loop, especially considering you don't seem to use it there.

Comment: By "trickery" I mean saving holder in tags. Android might reuse a view itself, but populate it with data from different item.